# Is there a mathematical classification of formal languages for denoting graphs as a sequence of finite symbols?

Tags: graphs, information-theory

I believe a general or pure definition of a “graph” in mathematics can be from algebraic topology, where a graph can be more abstractly seen as a simplicial complex, or a cell complex, or with scheme theory.

I am interesting in how many different “ways” a person could denote the structure of a given graph, in some notational language.

Assuming the notation of graph G is a finite sequence of symbols S from finite alphabet A, what ways are there to classify all possible notational languages?

The graph is a set of nodes and a set of edges, represented as pairs of elements they are connected to. Then a graph may be identifiable in other ways, for example, the set of all vertices, including “0-vertices” (a set of a single element) to denote the “vertex” from the element to itself.

The simplest language to denote a specific graph A would denote it with a single symbol, *a*. It would come with an interpretation file that symbol “a” refers to this particular graph, and write out the specifics of that graph.

This language is very long if we want to express more than one graph in fewer symbols than are required to spell out the graph in the current system we have (say, sets of edges, delimited by a delimiter symbol):

G|a,b|a||b,c|d|

is the graph with elements a, b, c, and d, and edges between a and b, and b and c.

There are many creative directions we can go. For example, we can have a language where it’s implied that the number of symbols between two symbols is the degree of the connection between them - this language can be used to infer which graphs meet that description, like this:

G: abcd

This means that we have an edge AB, BC, and CD, and there are two edges between A and C, and three between A and D. Obviously, the graph is a line of points.

We can keep changing the rules of interpretation.

But, we need a language to write those rules of interpretation *in*.

And, I want to do this to discover more fascinating or complex rules for denoting graphs, even if not practical. Imagine a complex language like, the degree of connection between each element and the first element is the distance. But for the second element, it’s the distance squared. And so on.

abcde

means AB deg 1, AC deg 2, BD deg 4 (2, to the power of 2), CE deg 8 (2 deg 3), etc.

So: how can one formulate this situation mathematically, and solve it?

I have 2 problems.

1. A language always has a language of interpretation. How do you begin? This is a classic problem. Is there a whole book discussing different options modern professionals have? Or is it all just basically type theories, nowadays?
2. Assuming we use a standard type theory like the calculus of inductive constructions. How do we specify a “graph” in it in a simple way, and can we somehow prove the number of ways a program can deterministically rewrite those symbols? This would imply the number of programs there are for parsing any notation into “simple” graph form.

We should then I think embed that number in a broader mathematical space. If we allow ourselves all kinds of functions like Max functions and real numbers and Cosin, etc, we might explore functions that transform the initial graph message into a new form, and analyze the relative change; is it reversible? Was information lost? If so, how much? For example, a function mapping every string to the string “a” has the highest level of information loss, because given the infinitude of inputs it takes, the output “a” can be the result of every possible expression in the entire formal language (the infinite free monoids of words over an alphabet).

So then, is the real question, restricting ourselves to a domain for the purpose of simplicity, and starting with the simplest possible rules constructible in a type theory, to classify them into equivalence classes based on how information-preserving (reversible) they are? Is that the *real* question here?